# convertir desde una cadena la primera letra de cada palabra a mayúscula java

Tags: java, string

Tengo el siguiente código,y mi duda es que al ejecutarlo se cambian todos las caracteres a mayúsculas, y únicamente quiero que se cambie el primer carácter a mayúscula,manteniendo el resto en minúsculas,pero no hay manera.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce una cadena ->");
    String cadena = sc.nextLine();
    String[] split = cadena.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < split[i].length(); j++) {
            if(j==0){
                System.out.print(split[i].toUpperCase().charAt(0));
            }else{
                System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase().charAt(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Si lo que buscas es solamente cambiar el primer caracter de una cadena a mayuscula podrias intentar con esto:

```
        // Obtener primera letra y convertirla a mayúscula
        String primeraLetra = cadena.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

        // Obtener el resto de la cadena, intacta
        String restoDeLaCadena = cadena.substring(1);

        // Concatenar
        String primeraMinuscula = primeraLetra + restoDeLaCadena;
```

Y si quieres forzar a que el resto de la cadena quede en minusculas intenta esto:

```
    // Obtener primera letra y convertirla a mayúscula
    String primeraLetra = cadena.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

    // Obtener el resto de la cadena, intacta.
    // Y convertir a minúscula
    String restoDeLaCadena = cadena.substring(1).toLowerCase();

    // Concatenar
    String primeraMinuscula = primeraLetra + restoDeLaCadena;
```

Answer (score 1):

puede realizarlo de la siguiente forma...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce una cadena ->");
        String cadena = sc.nextLine();
        String[] split = cadena.split("");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if(i == 0 || split[i-1].equals(" ")) {
                split[i] = split[i].toUpperCase();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.join("", split));
    }
```

En caso de que quiera evitar tanto codigo puede usar la siguiente libreria...

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

y luego invoca `StringUtils.capitalize(<string_variable>);`