# Usar to.UpperCase() en java para un arreglo

Tags: java, array, string

Tengo una duda con el to.UpperCase();

Estoy pidiéndole al usuario que digite su nombre para proceder a guardarlo en el  arreglo mediante el uso del for, pero quiero que se guarde en la posición (i), lo que digito el usuario pero todo en mayúscula. Se que lo puedo hacer primero guardando lo que digito el usuario en una variable y después haciéndole el to.UpperCase a esa misma variable, pero tengo la duda de si se puede hacer este proceso directamente.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length; i++) {

 System.out.println("\nPor favor ingrese el nombre de la persona # " + (i + 1));
    
nombre[i] = ct.nextLine();
```

Comment: Deberías plantear mejor tu pregunta y escribir el código que tengas para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar. Por ejemplo mencionas que el usuario digital su nombre, aquí está la base para partir, ya que puedes especificar de qué manera estás capturando los dígitos o si escribe toda la palabra y luego procedes a cambiarlos.

Comment: Hola ferny! Estoy capturando por medio de JOptionPane, pero también me sirve con Scanner y quiero que al momento de capturarlo se haga el proceso de cambiar a mayúscula y se guarde en la posicion(i)

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length; i++) {

                                    System.out.println("\nPor favor ingrese el nombre de la persona # " + (i + 1));
                                    nombre[i] = ct.nextLine();

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282906/convertir-desde-una-cadena-la-primera-letra-de-cada-palabra-a-may%C3%Báscula-java este post puede ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias Ferny pude resolverlo

Comment: Puedes publicar tu respuesta con el código que utilizaste para que mas personas que puedan tener el problema puedan resolverlo.

Comment: Respuesta: vector[i] = vector[i].toUpperCase();

Comment: @ValentinaGutierrez la solución va en la zona de respuestas por favor, recuerda leer [answer] y agregar una explicación de por que esa es la solución

Comment: Con "hacer este proceso directamente", ¿te refieres a usar `nombre[i] = ct.nextLine().toUpperCase();`? Por cierto, recuerda que es [`String.toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--) y no `String.UpperCase()` como pusiste en el título de tu pregunta.

Comment: Deberías tener cuidado con esto, si en algún escenario el valor de `nextLine()` es `null` el código se va a romper a causa de un NPE. Generalmente la lectura del Scanner se pone en un bucle `while` que verifica precisamente que la próxima línea no es `null`.